# How to avoid duplication with QueryOver

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I have two methods and don't like the duplication:

```
public Order LatestOrderOver(decimal amount)
{
    return session.QueryOver<Order>()
        .Where(o => o.Amount > amount)
        .OrderBy(sr => sr.CompleteUtcTime).Desc
        .Take(1)
        .SingleOrDefault<Order>();
}

public Order LatestAmericanOrderOver(decimal amount)
{
    return session.QueryOver<Order>()
        .Where(o => o.Amount > amount && o.Country == "USA")
        .OrderBy(sr => sr.CompleteUtcTime).Desc
        .Take(1)
        .SingleOrDefault<Order>();
}
```

What is the best way to avoid duplication when you have *similar criteria* (in the Where clause) used in the QueryOver and similar options at the end?

Comment: Why not just use `FirstOrDefault()` from `NHibernate.Linq` namespace instead of `Take(1).SingleOrDefault()`? Note: I'm not an nhibernate guy.

Comment: @hIpPy This is not Linq, but a QueryOver API. The methods just look like Linq methods. All of them are defined on `IQueryOver<T>` interface which doesn't inherit from `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Linq To Objects, you can just refactor out the delegate:

```
private Order LatestOrderOver(Func<Order, bool> f) {
  return
    session.QueryOver<Order>()
    .Where(f)
    .OrderBy(sr => sr.CompleteUtcTime).Desc
    .Take(1)
    .SingleOrDefault<Order>();
}

public Order LatestOrderOver(decimal amount) {
  return LatestOrderOver(o => o.Amount > amount);
}

public Order LatestAmericanOrderOver(decimal amount) {
  return LatestOrderOver(o => o.Amount > amount && o.Country == "USA");
}
```

Otherwise it might work with just changing `Func<>` to `Expression<>`, but I don't have much experience with that.

Comment: That's a great idea but I still have the duplication in the Where clause. In my real example the where clause is much more complicated with similar elements and different elements within it

Comment: @MichaelHedgpeth: You can also split the conditions and have one `Where` in the private method, and one `Where` in each method calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Beside Guffa's suggestion, what do you think about an extension method?

```
public static class QueryOverExtensions
{
    public static Order LastOrder(this IQueryOver<Order, Order> query)
    {
        return query
            .Where(o => o.Amount > amount)
            .OrderBy(sr => sr.CompleteUtcTime).Desc
            .Take(1)
            .SingleOrDefault<Order>();
    }

    // Other query over extension methods
}
```

Then you could write your methods as:

```
public Order LatestOrderOver(decimal amount)
{
    return session.QueryOver<Order>()
       .LastOrder();
}

public Order LatestAmericanOrderOver()
{
    return session.QueryOver<Order>()
        .Where(o => o.Country == "USA")
        .LastOrder();
}
```

Comment: That's a great idea but I still have the duplication in the Where clause.  In my real example the where clause is much more complicated with similar elements and different elements within it.

Comment: How about now? I have moved the common where clause to the extension method. Note that I'm not 100% sure this will work with QueryOver. It works with (NHibernate) Linq. You can write `.Where(o => <first condition>).Where(o => <second condition>).Where...` in Linq.

Comment: Heh, just realized that Guffa mentioned the same thing :)